# wait for last instance of program

Tags: windows, winapi, multiprocessing

I have two programs, X is the normal program with which the user interacts, and program Y which cleans up the resources acquired by program Y. There can be multiple instances of X but only one of Y (I already solved that part with named mutexes). Now, since Y is a cleanup program, it should be blocked until the last instance of X disappear.

I tried using a semaphore but I couldn't figure it out. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semaphore is *one* valid way of doing this, but not necessarily the best. Whenever program X starts, call `ReleaseSemaphore`. Whenever a process terminates, call `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout of zero on the semaphore handle (be sure to also include this in the exception handler, in case the program crashes).
Process Y can regularly poll `WaitForSingleObject` with a zero (or a few milliseconds) timeout then. If the return value is `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, it must release the semaphore again immediately (otherwise it will block the last X process trying to exit!). If the return value is `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, there are not X processes any more.

The *best* solution would of course be to launch all X processes from Y. In that case, Y could just `WaitForMultipleObjects` on the process handles that it gets from `CreateProcess` with no extra "ifs and whens". This will "just work", always. It is more efficient, too.
Which leads to the second best solution... getting handles to the running processes with `OpenProcess` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` on those. The problem is where to get the process IDs from. A shared memory area might do, a pipe might do, or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` might give you that info.

Another way would be to use a named mutex object. All processes X call `CreateMutex`. If the mutex already exists, no harm is done (GetLastError will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, but so what). If the process terminates or crashes, all open handles are closed, and thus the mutex reference count is decremented.
The Y process calls `OpenMutex`. This either succeeds or fails. If it succeeds, it closes the handle again, sleeps, and tries again. If it fails, no single X process is running.

Yet another way (though it might possibly have race issues) would be creating a named shared memory segment and calling `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` at process X start and exit. Process Y knows that no X processes are running if either the shared memory object cannot be opened or the counter is zero.